# Where do I save my files to be imported into TeXShop?

Tags: graphics

I'm new to TeXShop. I have a jpeg called "figure1" in my folder containing my TeX files. Yet, when I hit "Typeset" I get an error that the file isn't found. What can I do?

```
\documentclass[reprint, amsmath,amssymb, aps,]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{figure1}
  \caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{figure2}
  \caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A figure with two subfigures}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Create a `texmf` folder inside `~/Library` and, inside it, a `tex` folder; again, inside it a folder `mygraphics` where you can put your pictures. Any number of folders can be used along with `mygraphics`, with any name (but the more folders you have, the slower is looking into all of them).

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to submit a paper, you will need the picture files, so it's better to have them sitting in the same folder as the LaTeX file.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the reply. They are already in the same folder as the LaTeX file.

Comment: The only problem I can see is that you're typesetting with `latex+dvips+ps2pdf` instead of directly with `pdflatex`

Comment: @egreg Thanks. How do I change that?

Comment: @user62177 In the Preferences of TeXShop, click for the Typesetting tab; in the subpanel “Default Script” you should have `Pdftex` marked; if not, mark it.